# How can I create a new service account for Google Compute Engine VMs?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

None of the VMs I create on Compute Engine are able to access Google APIs. I think this is a serious issue that needs to be addressed, but after three days of no one at Google doing anything about it, it seems like the people who work on GCP disagree.

I want to create a new service account for the VMs to use and see if VMs using that service account are able to use Google APIs. I need to do this without deleting the old service account so machines that are currently running are not affected.

Answer (score 3):

Each VM automatically gets a service account. At creation time you can specify which GCE API it might access. After creation of the VM you can see the service account in the cloud console and give it access to other API like calendar, etc.